# TypeError: _co.post is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make an addition with an angular API but it gives me the error "ERROR TypeError:"

```
_co.post is not defined
```

**post.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  posts:any[]=[];

  post:{
    id:0,
    title:'',
    body:'',
    userId:''
  };


  constructor( private http:Http ) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
     .subscribe(Response=>{
       this.posts=Response.json()
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createPost(){
    this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',this.post)
    .subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response.json())
    })
  }

}
```

**post.component.html**

```
<form>
    <legend>New post</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">label</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="post.title" type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">label</label>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="post.body" type="text" name="body" id="body"  class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="body"></textarea>
    </div>



    <button (click)="createPost()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<p>{{ post | json }}</p>


<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts">
           <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
           <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
import { EmailService } from './email.service';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    FavoriteComponent,
    PanelComponent,
    InputFormatDirective,
    ContactFormComponent,
    SignupFormComponent,
    PostsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService,
    EmailService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: not related, but.... why are you using `Http` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: I am a beginner in angular and I use angular 8

Comment: You should consider switching from `Http` to `HttpClient` (from the `@angular/common/http` package) as well as `HttpModule` to `HttpClientModule`, and adjust your code accordingly to the `HttpClient` API (check here https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: `HttpClient` was introduced in version 4 (if I remember correctly) so I strongly suggest you move on to that. Even the documentation does not have `Http`, but `HttpClient`. You should read the official documentation so that you are "up to date" so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change post property in `post.component.ts`.

```
post:{
    id:0,
    title:'',
    body:'',
    userId:''
  };

TO

  post: any ={
    id:0,
    title:'',
    body:'',
    userId:''
  };
```

Comment: Better than that, change the post object to an interface and enjoy the benefits of typescript.